# Log4j DailyRollingFileAppender date before the filename

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

Is there a way to configure DailyRollingFileAppender to put the date before the file name? i.e. 2017.07.05.log.err instead of log.err.2017.07.05.

This is my current configuration

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy.MM.dd" />
    <param name="file" value="./data/logs/log.err" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE}][%-5p [%c{1}]] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: can you try this once `log4j.appender.rollingAppender.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=F:/temp/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}filename.log`

Comment: @Manindar he has an xml configuration not a properties file.

Comment: Sorry for that, but he can try the same thing with <param> tag. Try this stuff, i am not sure, but it may give you some idea. `<param name="fileNamePattern" value="F:/temp/%d{yyyy-MM-‌​dd}filename.log" />`

Answer (score 0):

Before you configure log4j  ( e.g. using `BasicConfigurator.configure()` ) , set a property called `log4j.log.file` using :

`System.setProperty( "log4j.log.file", "your_file_name" );`

Or you can use `-Dlog4j.log.file=your_file_name` if you are using command line. But I guess you construct date runtime, so use `setProperty()`.

Your file name could be constructed runtime using

```
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(new Date()).toString();
String filename = "./data/logs/" + File.separator + dateString + ".log.err";
```

and specify the property in your log4j xml like :

`<param name="file" value="${log4j.log.file}" />`